# Optimization for web page with hundreds of images

Tags: php, image, apache

I have a web platform that creates single page sites .. with lots of images and backgrounds (100-400).
As you can guess it loads terribly slow  (if browser cache is disabled). The pages are mainly promo materials so they will be opened only one time in general (so browser cache does not play a role).

I don't have much access to the front end, and it is not a single page but a platform for generating content, so I need some sort of server solution.

Lazy loading is not possible, we have some custom postponed loading for half of the images.

We use CDN* server on production but it does not give great effects (at least for a single user).

Is there some general solution configuration for to help this case ?
Like apache optimization for to give priority to images, 
zipping all the images in one(few) requests.

Comment: You mean CND or CDN ?

Comment: Lots of tricks you can use. Compress. Concate to sprites, exchange what can be done to CSS. Also some "loading img" illustration that can be pre set can give the impression of speed, which often is as important as the actual speed. Also which page need to load 400 images? The more I think about it, have you tried some of the many suggestions that search engies give you?

Comment: Did you compress all the images? You also can pick the lighter images and put in one request, or limit the number of requests by second.

Comment: @lago Malanies can you give more details plz? "compress all images", "pick the lighter images and put in one request", "limit the number of requests by second" this all sound good

Answer (score 1):

If (further?) lazy loading is not possible, you could bundle rows of images into a single image to use as sprites, and display them using CSS `background` and `background-position` properties.

This would reduce the number of downloads required, but it would require more processing and storage space on the server side.

Comment: The majority of the images are deployed from a moderator so sprites of this kind are not possible.